# Convert lines of a File into CSV

Tags: python, csv

This is an algorithm to get all rows, that begin with "BO_ " in a text-file....

```
  with open("FILE.txt") as f:
     for line in f:
       if line.startswith('BO_ '):
         array+=line

     print(array)
```

this code gives me the following result:

```
BO_ 1
BO_ 2
BO_ 3
BO_ 4
BO_ 5
BO_ 6
....
```

Now.... is it possible to convert this into a `csv` format like this:

```
string=['BO_1','BO_2','BO_3',...]
```

I tried already the `csv` module, but wasn't able to manage it....

Comment: That's not CSV, that's a list.

Comment: It looks like you want to create a list of values. I suggest you find information online about python lists. In particular, the `append()` function will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the format you described isn't really CSV format per-say, but:

```
with open("FILE.txt") as f:
     bo_lines = [line for line in f if line.startswith('BO_')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the join function like so:

```
string = ','.join(array.split('\n'))
```

this will give you:

```
"BO_1,BO_2,BO_3,..."
```

This could then be saved as a .csv. From the way your question is phrased though, as others have pointed out, you might not be looking for a csv.

> **Edit:** as code apprentice pointed out, you might want to use .append() instead to create an array of all the lines of the file. Currently you are concatenating every line onto **"array"** which is really a string, not an array.

Comment: okay, thank you for the tip. The solution of Deep Space fits perfect for me. nevertheless, thanks!